# prevents app service on linux recycling if azure storage mount fails

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

we have a small nodejs site hosted on `app service on linux` serving static content (+ some middleware actions) from an [azure storage blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage) preventing whole site to recycle if new content are pushed onto the blob.

For some reasons, probably network ones, azure storage mount is sometimes detected as faulty and when connection is restaured, it triggers the whole `app service` to recycle blocking serving any contents meanwhile and prevents more friendly waiting message.

```
2019-11-30 15:33:16.726 ERROR - Azure storage volume kiteblob for site kite faulted.
2019-11-30 15:34:01.615 INFO  - Azure storage volume kiteblob for site kite became healthy. Recycling site.
```

any way to prevent this behavior without hardening the whole service ? it's a small website serving few number of pages/users for internal purpose.